# LINQ-to-XML: Selecting specific node value

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

```
<PKT>
   <Result Name="GetBalance" Success="1">
      <Returnset>
         <Balance Type="int" Value="0" />
      </Returnset>
   </Result>
</PKT>
```

Best way to get the value of `Balance` with LINQ-to-XML?

Answer (score 3):

```
var values = from e in XDocument.Load("MyFile.xml").Descendants("Balance")
             select e.Attribute("Value").Value;

foreach (var e in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("MyFile.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = doc.Descendants("Balance");

foreach (XElement e in elements)
{
    Console.Write(e.Attribute("Value").Value);
}
```

You can do it this way.
I typed the code directly here, you may want to confirm any typos.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to only get the value from the first occurrence of `Balance`, you could do.

```
var balance = (from n in XDocument.Load("MyFile.xml").Descendents("Balance")
               select n.Attributes("Value").Value).ToList().First();
```